# how to display more than one value in table?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio

I am displaying values from a database in a basic table in html.

```
 <table>
    <tr>
           <td>
              <strong><label>CONTAINER NUMBERS</label></strong> <br />
              <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblContainerNoMurphy"></asp:Label>
           </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td>
          <strong><label>NO OF PIECES</label></strong> <br />
          <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblNoOfPiecesMurphy"></asp:Label>
         </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

And I'm getting the values from the database here:

```
    JobPiece piece = new JobPiece(Company.Current.CompanyID);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(piece.ContainerNo))
     {
           lblContainerNoMurphy.Text = piece.ContainerNo;
     }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(piece.AdvisedQty))
     {
          lblNoOfPiecesMurphy.Text = piece.AdvisedQty;
    }
```

The problem is that a job has many container numbers and number of pieces but only one is getting displayed. How do I display the other values?

Comment: Label will always show one.You can use string builer to concatenate multiple strings or Use Listbox(etc etc)Basically anything to hold multiple text. or best use "Gridview"

Comment: Can you explain better what does "joab ha many container.."? In your code there is nothing wrong, what is in ContainerNo and AdvidesQty is shown. If you have an IEnumerable<JobPiece> you should use a datagrid or a repeater and bind them to the data source.

Comment: @Leonardo ContainerNo and AdvidesQty has many rows in the database

Comment: @beginner91 fine, but you're asking just for 1 row with your call 
piece = new JobPiece(...) so just that value will be displayed

Answer (score 0):

Simple to use control will be **GridView**.Fetch the values from the database and fill a datatable and use that datatable as gridview datasource.

```
GridView1.DataSource=YourDataSet.Tables[0];
GridView1.DataBind();
```

If you want to change the look of gridview you can easily do it using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use *Repeater* like this

**asp.net code**

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <strong><label>CONTAINER NUMBERS</label></strong><br />
                            <asp:Label runat="server"  Text='<%#Eval("name of the field to show from db ex: ContainerNo") %>' ID="lblContainerNoMurphy"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <strong><label>NO OF PIECES</label></strong><br />
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblNoOfPiecesMurphy" Text='<%#Eval("name of the field to show from db ex: AdvisedQty") %>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

**C# code**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<JobPiece> items;    // get your items from database and put it in this list

        // fill repeater with your data
        Repeater1.DataSource = items;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
```

[more information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe(v=vs.110).aspx)
.
[more information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804(v=vs.85).aspx)